# In R, how to get the results of combn() from a matrix into a vector without losing data?

Tags: r, vector, combn

I know that combn() can give me all the unique combinations across a vector. However, it gives me a matrix output, and I want it as a vector. Wrapping the output in as.vector() makes every value individual, losing the purpose of running combn() in the first place. Imagine my dataset was c("a", "b", "c"), how can I use combn() (or some other function), to get a vector where my output would be:

```
my_data <- c("a", "b", "c")

#natural output with combn()

#output with combn()
combn(my_data, 2, simplify = TRUE)

#output with as.vector() wrapped
as.vector(combn(my_data, 2, simplify = TRUE))

#desired output
answer <- c("ab", "ac", "bc") #I don't care about order
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `paste` each column of the result together using `apply`

```r
my_data <- c("a", "b", "c")

apply(combn(my_data, 2), 2, paste, collapse = "")
#> [1] "ab" "ac" "bc"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We can use `combn` as

```
combn(my_data, 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "")
[1] "ab" "ac" "bc"
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! Is there a way to set paste's sep argument to a space? When I try paste(., sep = " "), I get an error.

Comment: @J.Sabree you need a lambda expression for that `combn(my_data, 2,  FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))`